# Android app: How to remove a view displayed by an Activity?

Tags: android

First I have a method which creates an activity which displays a view:

> Intent intent = new Intent(viewController, TestActivity.class);
>
> viewController.TestActivity(intent);

My TestActivity class calls setContentView(layout) and displays a view.

This works fine, my problem is trying to remove the Intent/View from the screen. I know I can call destroy() from within my Activity, however I am trying to remove the view from outside of the Activity class. I want the class which created the Activity/Intent to be able to remove it as well.

Any ideas? It seems like this should be a trivial fix however I'm unable to find the solution online for some reason. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Make a sigleton-like pattern to get the instance of the started activity.

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity{

  private static TestActivity instance;

  public static TestActivity getInstance(){
      return instance;
  }

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
   //xxxxx
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      instance = this;
  }

  protected void onDestroy(){
    //xxxxx
    super.onDestroy();
    instance = null;
  }

  public void finishOutSide(){
      this.finish();
  }
}
```

Then in the outside,use these code to finish the activity:

```
if(TestActivity.getInstance() != null){
   TestActivity.getInstance().finishOutSide();
}
```

Comment: Very clever I like this idea!

Answer (score 0):

All of your `Activity` instances can be destroyed when the sustem is running low on memory. Hence, it causes unexpected behaviour. Finish an `Activity` itside itself only or in a foreground `Service` that cannote be unexpectedly killed.

You have to rethink your application architecture to avoid such issue.